# Serial Communication breaks down when threading

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port, python-multithreading, virtual-serial-port

I am using a USB microwave source, which communicates via a virtual COM port.

Communication is done via python. Everything works fine, as long as I am executing the code blockingly.

However, as soon as any communication is done in a thread
I get a `SerialException: Attempting to use a port that is not open`. Is there an obvious reason, why this is happening? Nothing else, at least originating from my software, is trying to communicate with the port during that time.

The highest level script:

```
from serial import SerialException

import deer
import windfreak_usb

try:
    deer.mw_targets = windfreak_usb.WindfreakSynthesizer()
except SerialException:
    deer.mw_targets.port.close()
    deer.mw_targets = windfreak_usb.WindfreakSynthesizer()

deer_mes = deer.DeerMeasurement(f_start=0.9e9,
                                f_end=1.2e9,
                                df=3e6,
                                f_nv=1.704e9,
                                seq=["[(['mw'],28),([],tau),(['mw', 'mwy'],56),([],tau),(['mw'],28),([],100)]",
                                     "[(['mw'],28),([],tau),(['mw', 'mwy'],56),([],tau),(['mw'],84),([],100)]"],
                                power_nv=10,
                                power_targets=3,
                                tau=700
                                )

deer_mes.run(10e6)  # <- this works perfectly, as it is the blocking version
# deer_mes.start(10e6)  # <- raises the SerialException at the line indicated below
deer.mw_targets.port.close()
```

A reduced form of the microwave source (windfreak_usb.py):

```
import serial

import synthesizer


class WindfreakSynthesizer(synthesizer.Synthesizer):

    def __init__(self):
        synthesizer.Synthesizer.__init__(self)
        self.port = serial.Serial(
            port='COM14',
            baudrate=9600,
            timeout=10
        )
        self.off()

    def __del__(self):
        self.port.close()

    def off(self):
        self.port.write('o0')

    def power(self, p):
        p = int(p)
        self.port.write('a{}'.format(p))
```

A reduced form of the measurement class (deer.py):

```
import threading
import time

import numpy
import os
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import hardware
import matpickle
import pulsed
import pulser
import savepath
import synthesizer

if 'pg' not in globals():
    pg = pulser.Pulser()

if 'mw_targets' not in globals():
    mw_targets = synthesizer.Synthesizer()

timeout = 30
CurrentMeasurement = None  # global variable pointing to the currently active measurement


class DeerMeasurement(QObject):
    update = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, f_start, f_end, df, f_nv, seq, power_nv, power_targets, tau, sweeps_per_iteration=50e3,
                 switching_time=300e-6):
        super(QObject, self).__init__()
        """ setting all parameters as self.parameter """
        self.power_targets = power_targets

        self.fs = numpy.arange(f_start, f_end + df, df)
        self.abort = threading.Event()

        self.save_deer()

    def run(self, sweeps):

        global CurrentMeasurement
        if CurrentMeasurement is not None:
            print('Deer Warning: cannot start measurement while another one is already running. Returning...')
            return
        CurrentMeasurement = self

        # Start measurement
        print('Deer measurement started.')

        mw_targets.power(self.power_targets)  # <- This causes the SerialException.

        """ Here comes the actual measurement, that is never executed, as the line above kills the thread already with the SerialException. """

    def start(self, sweeps, monitor=None):
        """Start Measurement in a thread."""
        if monitor is not None:
            monitor.register(self)
        if not hasattr(self, 'mes_thread'):
            # noinspection PyAttributeOutsideInit
            self.mes_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=(sweeps,))
            self.mes_thread.start()
        else:
            print('Already threading')
```

Any help is highly appreciated, as running the measurement outside a thread is not an option.

Best regards!

Comment: can you post the whole listing of code? I suspect the thread might be opening a second instance of the serial device.

Comment: I tried your code and could not replicate your issue. See my full code [here](https://gist.github.com/AlexEshoo/22fd728ccb0f0417a337f32f393b80b7) Note that I'm using python3 so i had to pass a bytes obect to `write_power` since strings are unicode in python3, but I do not get any error about the serial port being in use elsewhere. Do you perhaps have another script still running that left the port open without closing it?

Comment: @holdenweb I think args=(p,) is correct, as the parameter the function needs is p.

Comment: @AlexEshoo your code looks pretty much like what I THINK mine is doing. Very strange. I will post my actual code (just shortened by really irrelevant stuff) in an edit of the original post.